# ¿Cómo cambio un campo de un INSERT con Sed?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, cut

Tengo un fichero de texto con datos de unas tablas de MySQL cuyo principio de linea empieza por **(1, (2,** y asi sucesivamente.

Un ejemplo de lo que tengo en dicha tabla es lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO `seriales_ordenador` (ID, SO, VERSION, SERIAL)
VALUES (1, 'Windows', 'XP', 'AAAAAAAAAAA'),
(2, 'Windows', 'XP', 'BBBBBBBBBBB'),
(3, 'Windows', '2000', 'CCCCCCCCCC');
```

Estoy intentando realizar lo siguiente para que me cambie el **(1, (2,** por el (NULL:

```
sed -i 's/(.*,/(NULL,/g' seriales_ordenador.sql
```

Cuando he ido a comprobarlo con un cat que no me lo realiza como quiero, sino que me hace cosas raras como lo siguiente:

```
(2(NULL, 'Windows(NULL,', 'XP(NULL,', 'BBBBBBBB(NULL,'.
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo para que me reemplazara el **(1, (2,...** por **(NULL,** en el principio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tema es que con `.*` estás cogiendo más de la cuenta. Además, el paréntesis "(" es carácter especial en Sed, por lo que debes escaparlo.

Por todo ello, sugiero hacer así:

```
sed -r 's/\([[:digit:]]+,/(NULL,/g' fichero
```

Es decir, busca `\([[:digit:]]+,` y reemplaza por `(NULL,`, donde `\([[:digit:]]+,` consiste en "(" seguido por uno o más dígitos y finalmente una coma.

Con tu fichero devuelve esto:

```
INSERT INTO `seriales_ordenador` (ID, SO, VERSION, SERIAL)
VALUES (NULL, 'Windows', 'XP', 'AAAAAAAAAAA'),
(NULL, 'Windows', 'XP', 'BBBBBBBBBBB'),
(NULL, 'Windows', '2000', 'CCCCCCCCCC');
```

Para hacer que el cambio se haga en tu propio archivo, usa `-i` como hacías, pero por seguridad añádele una extensión para tener un backup:  `sed -i.bak '...' fichero`.

Comment: Gracias por indicarlo, fedorqui.

Comment: Y gracias por indicarme como hacer las preguntas.

Comment: faltaría más! Si quieres añadir un nuevo paso a la experiencia [es.so], puedes leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)